# Interrupt a sleeping goroutine?

Tags: go

Is there a way in which I can execute, for example

```
time.Sleep(time.Second * 5000) //basically a long period of time
```

and then "wake up" the sleeping goroutine when I wish to do so?

I saw that there is a `Reset(d Duration)` in `Sleep.go` but I'm unable to invoke it.. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There isn't a way to interrupt a `time.Sleep`, however, you can make use of [`time.After`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#After), and a `select` statement to get the functionality you're after.

Simple example to show the basic idea:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    timeoutchan := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        <-time.After(2 * time.Second)
        timeoutchan <- true
    }()

    select {
    case <-timeoutchan:
        break
    case <-time.After(10 * time.Second):
        break
    }

    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/7uKfItZbKG

In this example, we're spawning a signalling goroutine to tell main to stop pausing.  The main is waiting and listening on two channels, `timeoutchan` (our signal) and the channel returned by `time.After`. When it receives on either of these channels, it will break out of the select and continue execution.