# How to use time.After() instead of time.Sleep() to obtain interruptible pause

Tags: go, concurrency, sleep, scheduler, channel

I have a program which periodically checks an external mailbox for messages and which has a user view which allows them to view messages and to terminate the program.

Stripped to minimal features it looks like this

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    log.Println("Hello, playground")

    quit := make(chan bool)
    data := make(chan string)

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-quit:
                log.Println("Quitting")
                close(data)
                return
            case data <- fetch():
                // Wait until e.g. exactly 0,10,20,30,40 or 50 mins past the hour
                interval := time.Second * 5
                now := time.Now()
                time.Sleep(now.Truncate(interval).Add(interval).Sub(now))
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(12 * time.Second) // actually user presses a "quit" button
        quit <- true
    }()

loop:
    for {
        select {
        case info, ok := <-data:
            if !ok {
                break loop
            }
            log.Println("Fetched", info)
        }
    }

    log.Println("Goodbye, playground")
}

func fetch() string {
    log.Println("Fetching")
    return "message"
}
```

You can [run this in the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cCCX9s3I6O)

Output is

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Hello, playground
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Fetching
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Fetched message
2009/11/10 23:00:05 Fetching
2009/11/10 23:00:05 Fetched message
2009/11/10 23:00:10 Fetching
2009/11/10 23:00:10 Fetched message
2009/11/10 23:00:15 Fetching
2009/11/10 23:00:15 Quitting
2009/11/10 23:00:15 Goodbye, playground
```

Notice that

- `"23:00:15 Fetching"` is something I didn't expect.
- The program quits at 23:00:15, not at 23:00:12 because it's sleeping.

The latter would be a problem in my program because it uses a 10 minute sleep between checking for messages. Delaying a quit for that long would make the program seem pretty unresponsive.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23331563/477035) I have learned that you can use `time.After()` to create a loop delay that can be interrupted.

How should I best apply that to my program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "23:00:15 Fetching" is something I didn't expect.

This is not surprising, this is the intended working. Quoting from [Spec: Select statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements):

> Execution of a "select" statement proceeds in several steps:
>
> 1. For all the cases in the statement, the channel operands of receive operations and the channel and right-hand-side expressions of send statements are evaluated exactly once, in source order, upon entering the "select" statement.
>
> [...]

So the `select` statement evaluates the communication operations before it decides on which branch to proceed / execute.

This means that

```
case data <- fetch():
```

`fetch()` will be called, even if sending on `data` would not be possible and even if receiving from `quit` can proceed immediately.

Since you have the sleep in one of the `case` branches, it doesn't matter that `quit` becomes ready to receive from, checking that (and optionally deciding to go on that branch) has to wait until `time.Sleep()` –and the whole `case` branch– completes.

So the communication operation should be a receive operation from the channel returned by [`time.After()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After), and only call `fetch()` in the body of this case branch.

You can make it work like this:

```
for {
    // Wait until e.g. exactly 0,10,20,30,40 or 50 mins past the hour
    interval := time.Second * 5
    now := time.Now()
    delay := now.Truncate(interval).Add(interval).Sub(now)

    select {
    case <-quit:
        log.Println("Quitting")
        close(data)
        return
    case <-time.After(delay):
        data <- fetch()
    }
}
```

And now the output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Mnb_Sb54zi)):

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Hello, playground
2009/11/10 23:00:05 Fetching
2009/11/10 23:00:05 Fetched message
2009/11/10 23:00:10 Fetching
2009/11/10 23:00:10 Fetched message
2009/11/10 23:00:12 Quitting
2009/11/10 23:00:12 Goodbye, playground
```