# How to add wait time in for loop

Tags: go

I have a list of files that I have to process on 5sec interval.

Here is the main method:

```
func main() {
    pusher := pusher.NewPusher(10)
    // goroutine to consume channel
    go pusher.Start()

    shutdownGatherer := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 5)
        defer ticker.Stop()
        for {
            select {
            case <-shutdownGatherer:
                log.Infof("Gatherer received shutdown signal, stopping.")
                return
            case t := <-ticker.C:
                log.Infof("\n **** Gatherer Tick at: %s ****\n", t)
                go gather(pusher)
            }
        }
    }()
    log.Infof("Done.")
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1000)
}
```

The gather method has to add some wait time (random O to 5sec) to each file before it adds to the channel:

```
func gather(p *pusher.Pusher) {
    regularFilePaths, _ := filepath.Glob("../files/*")
    for _, filePath := range regularFilePaths {
        p.Enqueue(filePath)
    }
}
```

You can find the pusher file here: [pusher.go](https://play.golang.org/p/1BRZe19ysQG)

Imagine we have files:

- test1.txt
- test2.txt
- ...
- test100.txt

  ```
        First interval: 
        2sec sleep --> Add test1.txt to channel for processing
        3sec sleep --> Add test2.txt to channel for processing
        5sec passed

    -----------

        Second interval: 
        1sec sleep --> Add test3.txt to channel for processing
        2sec sleep --> Add test4.txt to channel for processing
        3sec sleep --> Add test5.txt to channel for processing
        5sec passed

    -----------

        3rd interval: 
        5sec sleep --> Add test6.txt to channel for processing
        5sec passed
  ```

  ---

  etc

My problem is the sleep, takes longer than 5sec ticker interval.
And seems sleep does not work as expected.

Could you please offer me a better approach here:

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891350/how-to-use-time-after-instead-of-time-sleep-to-obtain-interruptible-pause

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a constant wait, in most production environments we want to use a rate limiter.  Token Bucket is a great implementing, here is Uber's Go implementation.

https://github.com/uber-go/ratelimit